# Can a ListView item be complex?

Tags: android

I have a set of views that I need to present in a list-like manner. Every view is rather complicated, but each is a clone of the previous, just with different data. Now, there is a *lot* of data on any given view, so is a ListView/ListActivity still the right thing to use here? Or are those only intended for simple views that show just one or two text items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ListViews can be used to display complex views as you seem to have.  However, ListViews are especially useful if you don't know the number of views to display until runtime and have some datastore behind that is being displayed.

If you have a fixed number of views to display, a FrameLayout or other ViewGroup might be a better choice.

Comment: Ah, I suppose that answers the question then. However, I'm not yet going to throw down that green checkmark just yet, because I'm still confused. I do indeed have a datastore, and not a fixed dataset. But I've been hunting around the android docs, and I can't find a single scrap of information on doing anything with a ListView other than displaying rows with predefined things like android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item. Are there any guides for this sort of thing, or are you basically on your own?

Comment: ListViews have a ListAdapter.  When you create your own ListAdapter, you can override `getView()` to return the appropriate view of your choice, either inflating it from a resource, building it in the code, or returning/reusing a cached instance.  Details on this are here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html

Comment: Perfect thanks. I suppose there might not be a tutorial from google on this, but based on what you've just said, I think I can fiddle around and figure it out :-)

Comment: ListView might be the most thoroughly covered topic in the Android UI toolkit. :) This video might be useful to you as well: http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html